# Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just upgraded my application to `ember 2.1` and am getting this error in my web browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function
```

In my url, I have a variable named `direction`:

```
http://localhost:4200/plates/new?direction=plates
```

Then I build this into my controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['direction'],
    direction: null,
    actions: {
        lastpage(){
            this.transitionTo(this.get('direction'));
            },
       save(...){
            },  

        },  
    });
```

This used to work before my upgrade. What depreciated / how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From a controller you need to use `this.transitionToRoute` instead of `this.transitionTo`.  This has been deprecated for much of 1.x.

Answer (score 3):

`Controller` does not have a method [`transitionTo`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo). It is a method of `Route`. Controller has method [`transitionToRoute`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute).